# Android 12 app crashes when users grants approximate location permission

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

When requesting location from the user, if approximate location is selected rather than exact location, the app crashes unexpectedly.

Logcat gives the error simply "permission is null".

In my manifest I am stating

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and in my request I am simultaneously requesting both fine and course, as specified in [googles guide here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request)

```
const getPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
]);
```

At this point, the app will crash, and only through logcat can I see the error

```
02-03 12:21:46.736 15320 15395 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: permission is null
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace, not just the first line - some function is being called with a parameter that's not allowed to be null, but we need the rest of the trace to actually tell what it is